# `asdf list-all erlang` not showing recent versions

Tags: asdf-vm

I am trying to install erlang OTP 22.2.8 via asdf, after following [this setup guide](https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-asdf). When I view the list of available versions, the most recent I can see is v19.

```
R13B03
R13B04
R14A
...
19.0.1
19.0.2
```

Sys info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```